# Pruning "unmaintained" roses

Tags: pruning, roses

I am not a gardener, but I have however found myself in stewardship of 3 rose plants planted in beds, each in memory of folks who've crossed over. They have never been pruned. The only clue I can give to their breeds are red, yellow, and pink. We are in the south west of England, this is posted in early March.

Each plant's stalks are never even 1cm thick, each is at least half green stalks (as opposed to woody) up to maybe 3-5mm thick.  The biggest is maybe about 3 feet "tall" (although it's leaning over), the smallest about 1 foot.  They are all showing some new leaves at the moment.  They reliably show a few blooms each year. To my eye they are "stringy".

Should I prune them at all this year, or is it too late, and if yes then to what degree? I don't want to kill them, or let them die by inaction!

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Pictures, please? There are not only different cultivars, much more important is the growth type. A hybrid tea needs different care than, say, a rambler.

Answer (score 2):

Most roses are tough as old boots so don't worry too much about harming them.  It doesn't sound like they are climbers or ramblers as they haven't made long vigorous growth. You want them growing in bare soil not choked by grass, weeds or other plants. Then take a look at the advice given by the RHS [here](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/roses/pruning-guide).